# Don't execute FIRST statement if SECOND statement failed SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to execute the whole procedure at one block which prevents a massive data lose if a user has stopped the query execution before second statement runs.

SET XACT_ABORT ON abort the batch when an error occurs I kind of need something similar when Execution is stopped by user.

```
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Users] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Statement 1:
   DELETE FROM Users

    -- Statement 2:
   INSERT INTO Users VALUES 
   (1,'John','Whatever')
   ,(4,'Jessy',NULL)
   ,(5,'Adam',NULL)

END
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use transactions.  And just roll back the transaction if anything occurs.

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures and should **not** be used for user procedures. Doing so can result in your procedure simply not working one day, and comes with performance costs. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?(https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Yeah I should've named it spUsers didn't notice that when posting

Answer (score 0):

I think using a transaction with an error conditional statement could work.  All within a transaction, you can run the first delete statement.  Then, you could look for an error using the MS SQL global variable @@ERROR to determine whether the proc should continue on to the second statement.  If all is well, then the transaction is committed, or else the whole transaction is rolled back.  For the global variable, if you're not looking for an error but rather rows affected, @@ROWCOUNT could help.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION StatementsTest
      -- Statement 1:
    DELETE FROM Users

IF  @@ERROR = 0
    BEGIN
    -- Statement 2:
    INSERT INTO Users VALUES 
    (1,'John','Whatever')
    ,(4,'Jessy',NULL)
    ,(5,'Adam',NULL)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION StatementsTest
    END
ELSE    
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION StatementsTest
    END
```